# How VSCode injects "vscode" engine into the extensions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When developing extensions for VSCode. We see this import:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
```

and in `package.json`, we have

```
"engines": {
  "vscode": "*"
}
```

Nowhere in the dependencies we have 'vscode'. But, looks like it is available for extension. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Imports are resolved by the host environment, in this case VSCode's possibly-modified version of Electron. So when it sees a request for the `vscode` module, it provides it (internally) rather than looking for an external dependency.

FWIW, a defacto standard is emerging that "raw" module names, like `'vscode'`, tend to be provided directly by the host environment whereas ones with paths (`'./foo'`) are external. (That's why the `src` on `script type="module"` tags is required to have a path, at least for now.)

Comment: Thanks! So, I found this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-loader

Do you think they are using this?

Comment: Entirely possible, VSCode is open source... But I wouldn't know either way.

Answer (score 1):

The "engines" section in `package.json` is not related with module import system.
It's for some native module to know howto compile when `npm install`.
And can check engine version. eg: you can set `engines: {node: >=8}`, then node v7 will deny to run your code, but that's not enforce.

VS Code is using `vscode-loader` as module loader, it's very like `require.js`, but has many other function for vscode.
The "global" function "require" you called, is override by vscode-loader, not node's native "require".
Same with any other module loader system, vscode-loader allows you to modify the "require" function.

vscode is changing so fast, you can do a simple search with `nodeRequire('module')`.

Currentlly, related code is in `src/vs/workbench/api/node/extHost.api.impl.ts` file:

```
const node_module = <any>require.__$__nodeRequire('module');
const original = node_module._load;
node_module._load = function load(request: string, parent: any, isMain: any) {
    if (request !== 'vscode') {
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    .....
    .....
    // and finally, return apiImpl, the "vscode" object
}
```

`require()` will call `module._load()`, but this `module._load` is already overrided by vscode-loader.
You can also override it again like this.
That is called **"Monkey Patch"**.